# Separação nos elementos de uma list em impar e par

Tags: python

```
valores = []
par = []
impar = []
soma_par = 0
soma_impar = 0

while True:
  x = int(input())
  valores.append(x)
  if x == 0:
    break
  for item in valores:
    if item % 2 == 0:
      par.append(item)
    elif item % 2 != 0:
      impar.append(item)

for numero in par:
  soma_par = soma_par + numero

for num in impar:
  soma_impar = soma_impar + num

soma_total = soma_par + soma_impar

print(soma_par)
print(soma_impar)
print(soma_total)
```

Eu quero separar corretamente os itens da list valores em par e impar para então mostrar o usuário a soma dos números pares, soma dos números impares e a soma total dos números que ele colocou no input

A saída que eu quero, por exemplo: [Usuário inseriu 3, 2 e 1]
Soma Par = 2
Soma Impar = 4
Soma Total = 6

A saída que está saindo:
Soma Par = 4
Soma Impar = 6
Soma Total = 10

Onde está o problema e como poderia resolver?

Comment: Cada vez que você lê um novo número você percorre todos os lidos anteriormente separando-os como pares e ímpares. Ao invés de `for item in valores` você pode apenas validar o `x`.

Comment: Mas vc precisa guardar todos os números digitados, ou só quer saber a soma? Se for só pra calcular a soma, nem precisa dessas listas todas, basta ir atualizando as somas à medida em que os números são lidos: [veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/jubpum) - Note também que o resto da divisão por 2 só pode ser 0 ou 1, então se não é zero, com certeza é 1 e não precisa testar de novo.

Comment: só preciso saber a soma, com o seu exemplo ficou bem mais claro, eu agradeço
não sabia sobre o +=, mas com ele o código fica muito mais limpo

Answer (score -4, accepted):

O código está com um problema de lógica. A estrutura 'for' precisa estar fora da repetição 'while'

caso contrário os número serão adicionados as listas várias vezes durante a execução.

```
valores = []
par = []
impar = []
soma_par = 0
soma_impar = 0

while True:
    x = int(input())
    valores.append(x)
    if x == 0:
        break

for item in valores:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        par.append(item)
    elif item % 2 != 0:
        impar.append(item)

for numero in par:
    soma_par = soma_par + numero

for num in impar:
    soma_impar = soma_impar + num

soma_total = soma_par + soma_impar

print(soma_par)
print(soma_impar)
print(soma_total)
```

tente estudar um pouco mais de lógica da programação, pense que 'enquanto' algo for verdade as proximas linhas serão executadas infitas vezes até que a condição se satisfaça...

parece confuso mas tente escrever num papel para começar a entender a lógica

Comment: Agradeço, funcionou perfeitamente!